# Cancel the keydown in an HTML page?

Tags: javascript, html, keydown

How can I cancel the keydown of a button on the keyboard in an HTML page.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's somewhat more complicated than described so far, see [Quirksmode.org](http://quirksmode.org/dom/events/index.html#t09):

> You cannot prevent the default `onkeydown` in Opera.

In Opera, use `onkeypress` instead.

Comment: Correct. I think Jan Wolter's article at http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html is the definitive work on JavaScript key events.

Answer (score 2):

Handle the `onkeydown` event and `return false;`

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
<input type="button" onkeydown="return false;" />
```